# What exactly was the plan that drove the bulk of the Southlands subplot?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-rings-of-power

By the end of the first season of The Rings of Power, we learn that

> the tunnels were constructed to channel water to Mt. Doom, and Sauron's sword was the key that unlocked the dam

So...whose plan was this, and what exactly was the plan? For example...

> Did Sauron make the sword and the dam with the idea that this needed to happen, but it just didn't happen in his time, so Adar was just executing the plan?

Or,

> Did Adar know about the dam and the key, and made up the plan from there? But then what is the significance of the dam, why is that *the* thing that Sauron links his sword to?

And given that

> Arondir could take down the tower with a single arrow, why not just figure out a way to sabotage the dam?

Comment: Is this not a question that will be answered in the second season?

Comment: @DonatelloSwansino It certainly _felt_ like a complete story arc - there was a plan that was being formulated, certain elements needed to happen and did happen, the plan was executed, and the mission was accomplished. Maybe we'll get some dialogue in the future about whose plan it was though!

Comment: Regarding your last point, would Arondir know to sabotage the dam? From what I recall, no one knew the extent of the digging the orcs had done nor that using the hilt would shatter the dam. Unless I missed something, *I* wasn't even aware it was a dam until the hilt was used and the water broke through.

Comment: @goat_fab - I think OP is asking why didn't Adar just destroy the dam when he couldn't find the magic sword.

Comment: The better question is: why is Adar so seemingly against Sauron, but does everything in his power to bring him back and enact his plans?

Comment: @Möoz Does he, though?

Comment: It was Morgoth's plan, set up by Sauron, if I haven't got my wires crossed. It was discussed in interviews, I believe, I can't recall where I heard/read it. It was a bit of a backup in case (iirc) the War of Wrath went badly.

Comment: @DavidRoberts if you ever find that source let me know!

Comment: @Brendan probably a Sauron-actor interview after the show finale, if that helps cut things down. There's a big playlist on YT of RoP interviews, it might be in there.

Comment: @Möoz Adar is trying to establish the Orc homeland.  That's been his life's obsession for some centuries, it appears.   Many objectives, in their pursuit, bring along unintended side effects.   I am still not sure if he was lying to Halbrand or not as regards his response to "remember me?"